# Set the time of datetime column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have a dataframe that it has a datetime column 'started_at'

| started_at |
| --- |
| 2019-12-03 10:33:06 |
| 2019-12-03 12:29:37 |
| 2019-12-03 18:29:37 |
| 2019-12-04 11:29:37 |

I would like to change the time to it, if the time is smaller that a specific time (12:00)

So, the data should become:

| started_at |
| --- |
| 2019-12-03 12:00:00 |
| 2019-12-03 12:29:37 |
| 2019-12-03 18:29:37 |
| 2019-12-04 12:00:00 |

Any suggestions?

Comment: Calculate a timedelta between the given datetime and the given date with time set to noon.

Comment: how should I do that on the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
import datetime as dt
for i in range(len(df)):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    val = dt.datetime.strptime(str(df.loc[i][0]), fmt )
    new_val = dt.datetime.strptime(str(df.loc[i][0]).split(" ")[0] + " 12:00:00", fmt )
    if val < new_val:
        df["started_at"] = df["started_at"].replace(val,new_val)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first apply a mask for your times under '12':

```
mask=df["started_at"].dt.hour<12
```

Then I would modify the values according to that mask:

```
df[mask]=df['started_at'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 12:00:00")
```

Comment: My dataframe has multiple columns (I did not post it above)

@daniel-weigel  

So, when I trie your suggestion, I get:

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"